# fetchObjectsForEntityName: not recognised as valid method

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This code is really confusing me. When I type in fetchObjectsForEntityName, it doesn't offer suggestions, and then afterwards gives me a warning of `No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObjectContext' declares the selector 'fetchObjectsForEntityName:withPredicate:'`.

Here's the code:

```
-(SyncObject *)objectWithSyncID:(NSString *)syncID inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"syncID == %@", syncID];

    NSSet *set = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"SyncObject" withPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the method doesn't exist. I guess you copied some code from a tutorial but you didn't copy all of it. There should be a category on `NSManagedObjectContext` which defines and implements the method.

Comment: Perhaps from here: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/core-data-one-line-fetch.html.

Comment: Ah, i copy and pasted it from another class, so forgot that i'd used a category for that.